# Why is the regex match throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, regex

I've been given this Regex to use in a project, and it doesn't seem to be working correctly - it worked before in other applications.

It tells me `parsing "((^[^_]{1}\S{1,40})\_(\S{5,6})\_(\S{1,4})\_(\S{1,4})\_(\S{4,6}))(\.{1}\S{1,5})$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.`

I have the regular expression in a file as a constant:

```
public static string MatchDocument = @"((^[^_]{1}\S{1,40})\_(\S{5,6})\_(\S{1,4})\_(\S{1,4})\_(\S{4,6}))(\.{1}\S{1,5})$";
```

I'm not that experience with regular expressions, but I assumed prepending the string with `@` would solve any backslash problems...why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means exactly what it says.

`\_` is not a regular expression escape sequence (in the .NET flavor of regular expressions).

If you want an underscore, just use `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains several instances of `\_`. This is not a valid regex escape.

Answer (score 0):

An underscore is a literal character and doesn't need escaping.